# Unable to create a Web service client on Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, web-services, wsdl, client

I tried to create a new web client on IDE Eclipse (2019-09R(4.13.0) Build id: 20190917-1200)
For reproduce this issue on Eclipse open dialog File->New->Other->Web Services->Web service client. In the service definition field enter url address. For eample I entered web address https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/airavata/sandbox/xbaya-web/test/Calculator.wsdl to the service definition field and buttons "Next" and "FINISH" was disabled. See picrue [image: Web Service Client dialog]
And I got an error "No server can be found and WebServiceProject does not exist. Choose an existing project or use the preferences to configure a server runtime."
How can I solve it. Please help.